# Time series data and utc conversion

Tags: database-design, timezone, time

I'm storing data in minute, hour, day, month and year buckets. All data is stored in UTC. Let's assume a client is in PDT time (-07:00 UTC)

If the client wants to query for the hour sum of `4/23/2016 7:00pm` in their timezone they would convert the time to UTC - `4/24/2016 2:00am` and make the query. Image for reference.

[image: Hour conversion from PDT to UTC]

This works perfectly fine for hour and minute buckets. However, let's look at the case where the client wants the sum for a day bucket. If the client wants the local day dum for `4/24/2016` they would convert the time to UTC which resolves in `4/24/2016` also. The `4/24/2016` UTC day bucket contains data for 7 hours from the local day `4/23/2016` and misses the last 7 hours of the local day `4/24/2016`. This seems like a problem since the query will not return the correct sum. It returns the sum for the UTC day.

Am I missing something with this example? Or is storing data buckets in time intervals > hour a bad idea?

Comment: Oh, there's a lot more to consider in this space.  Daylight saving time means you don't necessarily have a consistent offset (the day might start in -8 and end in -7, or vice versa).  It might not be 24 hours long.  Some time zones are 30 minute or 45 minute offset, etc.  Your buckets would need to be 15 minutes in size to cover all edge cases, and you'll have to adjust your query inputs dynamically.

Comment: What is a bucket? Isn't this just timestamped data?